# jQuery bind click not adding elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, grails

I have a button that when I click it more than once it is adding elements from the previous click.  It works fine the first time through.  We are using jQuery 1.11.1.

```
$(function() {
  $('a[name="generateReport"]').bind('click', function() {
    $(this).attr('href', $(this).attr('href') + '?est=' + est.value + '&prodcd=' + prodcd.value + '&startDate=' + startDate.value + '&endDate=' + endDate.value + '&tracking=' + tracking.value);
  })
})
```

What I am seeing is that the URL past to the server is adding the fields from the prior click.  This of course causes issues when it gets to the server.  Does this need to be cleared out after each click?

This is the code that calls it from our Grails app(2.4.3)

```
<g:link class="btn btn-primary" name="generateReport" controller="generateTTLReport" action="renderOutput">
                                <i class="icon-print icon-white"></i>
                                    Generate Report
                            </g:link>
```

Thanks,

Tom

Comment: As of jQuery 1.7, the .on() method is the preferred method for attaching event handlers to a document. Try changing your `.bind('click'` to `.on('click'`

Comment: @mikehomme - while this is true, `bind` should still work, and this would not be the reason for the issue

Comment: Where do you set the variables `est`, `prodcd`, `startDate`, etc.?

Comment: Does the page navigate away and refresh?

Comment: do u want to update the href only the first click ? remaining clicks should nt do anything.. is that wat ur expecting ?

Comment: @epascarello no it does not navigate away.

Comment: @Arkantos Is it possible to have it update everytime?  Should I set the href to a variable so I can avoid this issue?

Comment: If u want to update the href, can u give an example of how the url should be after 2 clicks ?

Comment: @Arkantos I would like it to look like http://localhost:8099/LSRTIS/generateTTLReport/renderOutput this instead of this http://localhost:8099/LSRTIS/generateTTLReport/renderOutput?est=&prodcd=&startDate=&endDate=&tracking=1797

Comment: *"no it does not navigate away"* Well there is your problem...You keep adding to the link....It does not magically remove the last stuff you added to the element.

Comment: so everytime you click on that button, your link url will be same till this part `http://localhost:8099/LSRTIS/generateTTLReport/renderOutput` but parameters `est, prodcd, startDate, endDate, tracking` should be changing.. is my understanding correct ?

Comment: @ epascarello Is there another means that you would suggest that may avoid this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Split the current href at the "?" to remove the query string parameters. Also, let jQuery build your new query string parameter string.

```
$(function() {
    $('a[name="generateReport"]').on('click', function() {
        var $this = $(this),
            path = $this.attr('href').split('?')[0],
            params = {
                est: est.value,
                prodcd: prodcd.value,
                startDate: startDate.value,
                endDate: endDate.value,
                tracking: tracking.value
            },
            href = [path, $.param(params)].join('?');

        $this.attr('href', href);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your code is, every time you click on that button, `bind` callback is invoked. So the first time you clicked, it got the `href` attribute added some parameters and replaced it. Again when you clicked on that for the second time, it does the same thing. It gets the `href` attribute which now contains parameters from previous update and then replace the existing. If you keep the href as it is, and only update the query parameters, you can define that as a global variable and use that in your event handler

You can hard code that link as a variable within in your script like this

```
$(function() {

  // define your variable within document.ready but outside your event handler
  var reportURL = '/LSRTIS/generateTTLReport/renderOutput';

  $('a[name="generateReport"]').bind('click', function() {
    var urlWithParams = reportURL + '?est=' + est.value + '&prodcd=' + prodcd.value + '&startDate=' + startDate.value + '&endDate=' + endDate.value + '&tracking=' + tracking.value;
    $(this).attr('href', urlWithParams );
  });
});
```

Hope this helps :)